# При компиляции dtc(device tree compiler) пишет об отсутствии файлов

Tags: кросс-компиляция

Пытаюсь, используя make, скомпилировать device tree compiler. Выводит по итогу это:

CHK version_gen.h
LEX dtc-lexer.lex.c
make: flex: Нет такого файла или каталога
BISON dtc-parser.tab.c
make: bison: Нет такого файла или каталога
LEX convert-dtsv0-lexer.lex.c
make: flex: Нет такого файла или каталога
make: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «convert-dtsv0-lexer.lex.c», требуемой для «convert-dtsv0-lexer.lex.o».  Останов.

Я понимаю, что там написано об их отсутствии, но мне непонятно почему так происходит, если я подтягиваю каталог dtc, используя ссылку, которая была предоставлена на сайте Xilinx.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Системе не хватало инструментов bison и flex. В моём случае (система Manjaro) решил всё, скачав тулсы:
pamac install flex;
pamac install bison